# Creating a client in C: does not connect to the server

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming

```
int createclientsock(char * hostname, int port){
struct hostent * hp;
printf("Attempting to create client socket!\n");
memset(&client_addr,'0',sizeof(client_addr));

client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
client_addr.sin_port = htons(port);  /* holds the remote port */

  /* If internet "a.d.c.d" address is specified, use inet_addr()
   * to convert it into real address.  If host name is specified,
   * use gethostbyname() to resolve its address */


client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname);      /* If "a.b.c.d" addr */
if (client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr == -1) {
    hp = gethostbyname(hostname);

    /* Call method to create server socketyname(hostname);*/
    /*printf("host name: %s",hp);*/
    if (hp == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Host name %s not found\n", hostname);
        exit(1);
    }
}

/* Create an Address Family (AF) stream socket, implying the use of tcp as the underlying protocol */
client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
printf("Client_fd: %d\n",client_fd);/*ANDY: it gets to here without printing errors, the client_fd = 3 ...im not sure what that means*/

/* use the sockaddr_in struct in the to variable to  connect */
if (connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, sizeof(client_addr)) < 0) {
  printf("ERROR: could not connect!\n");
  exit(1);
}

return client_fd;
```

}

It gets to the connect part and takes a long time before finally printing the error statement "ERROR: could not connect!\n"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your *actual* problem but the line:

```
memset(&client_addr,'0',sizeof(client_addr));
```

is probably not what you want. It's fills the structure with the *character* `'0'` rather than zero bytes. It would be better written as:

```
memset(&client_addr,'\0',sizeof(client_addr));
```

In addition, if you use a DNS name rather than an IP address, you never load it into the `client_addr` structure. You get back the `hostent` pointer but you should then use the `h_addr_list` field in that structure to populate `client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr`.

Comment: We have been doing this with local IPs. Our server is 192.168.5.1 and client is at 192.168.4.1 trying to connect to the server using that IP